# codeigniter Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: codeigniter

$account_types = $this->members_model->getAllAccountTypes();

```
$result_set = array();
foreach($account_types as $account_type){
    $result_set[$account_type->db_name] = array(
        'subscribed'   => $this->members_model->getAllSubscribedMembers($account_type->id),
        'unsubscribed' => $this->members_model->getAllUnsubscribedMembers($account_type->id)
    );
}
```

echo json_encode($result_set);

return;

i have these line of code which return me Trying to get property of non-object on foreach($account_types as $account_type)

Comment: Do `print_r($account_types);` and see what it's returning!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with following it will solved your problem :-

```
$result_set = array();
$account_types = json_decode(json_encode($account_types), true);
foreach($account_types as $account_type){
    $result_set[$account_type->db_name] = array(
        'subscribed'   => $this->members_model->getAllSubscribedMembers($account_type->id),
        'unsubscribed' => $this->members_model->getAllUnsubscribedMembers($account_type->id)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Always take care of your query results in the model**:

This could be possible that the query returns null so you better test the result first:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   foreach ($query->result() as $row)
   {
      echo $row->title;
      echo $row->name;
      echo $row->body;
   }
}
```

You can also pass a string to `result()` which represents a class to instantiate for each result object. [More Information](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/results.html)